# Set values for dynamically-created JQuery progress bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I have progress bars that are generated based on rows in a database query result set (obtained via MVC Razor):

```
foreach (var @row in rows) {
    <li>
        <div class="progress-bar id-@row.id"></div>
        <div class="label">@row.Name</div>
    </li>
}
```

The query results have a column called @row.Value, which is the value that the progress bar needs, but I'm trying to figure out how to set that value for each progress bar as it's created. I've tried various JQuery selectors, as well as calling a JavaScript function immediately after the progress bar div and passing in the @row.Value, but I can't seem to get it working.

Also, the progress bars are standard JQuery progress bars, currently set up this way:

```
$('.progress-bar').progressbar();
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

EDIT:

This ended up working for me:

```
$('#active-skill-list').find('li').each(function () {
    var progressBar = $(this).find('.progress-bar');
    progressBar.progressbar({
        value: progressBar.data('value')
    })
```

Comment: you talking about jquery ui progress bar, or something u done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talking about the jquery UI progress bar, you can simply add that value into your dom

```
foreach (var @row in rows) {
     <li>
       <div class="progress-bar id-@row.id" data-value="@row.value"></div>
        <div class="label">@row.Name</div>
    </li>
}
```

// something like this in your js part

```
$('YourUlContainer').find('li').each(function(){
    $(this).progressbar({ value: $(this).data('value') });
})
```

The goal is add that value into the dom, and trigger each li, with their value. But i would suggest you do it even simpler by using css, changing it's value with js instead of using the plugin unless is necessary.

Comment: I had to modify it a little bit to target the progress bar div instead of the li element, but your answer worked great!